# This rebus is gold (and loud)

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, visual, rebus, computer-puzzle

What **television programme** does this rebus stand for? Why is the rebus gold* and loud?

[image]

```
 1                    |  1                   
1                     | 11                   
   1                  |    1                 
  1                   |     1                
      1               |111                   
       1              |        1             
    1                 |         1            
     1                |          1           
           1          |            1         
             1        |              1       
1 1 111 11  111       |               1      
        1             |                1     
                 1    |   1 1  1   1         
         1            |  1  111   1     1    
 1 11 11 111 1   1    |                  1   
11111111       1      |1  1  11 11   1111    
         1   1  1     |                   1  
            1         |                    1 
1  11 11  11  1  11   |      1  1    1   1   
 11  1   111 11  1 1  |                     1
 1 1111   11  1  1  1 |  1 11111 1   1   1111
1 1    1  111 1      1|11  1111111111 1
```

---

> You might need to use [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org) for this.

> [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporadic_group) may help, alongside the use of GF(2).

<sub>*I'm red-green colourblind; this colour looks green to me. Thanks to [@Jerry Dean](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/75367/jerry-dean) for helping me identify this. Nevertheless, the English description of the colour is irrelevant to the puzzle.</sub>

Comment: Our man here is churning out quality puzzles at breakneck speed. _/ \\_

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora what is that symbol at the end? A pair of hands?

Comment: Yes. Good job, you solved the mini puzzle :'D

Comment: [This reminds me of something...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#/media/File:Pascal's_Triangle_animated_binary_rows.gif)

Comment: Well, I think I've probably identified the programme. Still puzzling about "gold and loud", but I know rather little about the programme in question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the rebus depicts

> the sporadic finite simple group known as the McLaughlin group, or McL for short; if we read blanks as 0 and greenish squares as 1, we have $<A,B>$ -- this is standard mathematical notation for a group generated by two elements -- where A,B are two matrices over the finite field of order 2, and these generate a faithful representation of that group; there are in fact lots of pairs of 22x22 binary matrices for which that would be true, but these are the specific ones found in the [Atlas of Finite Simple Groups](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/spor/McL/) -- on that page, find the section on representations, and look at the "dimension 22 over GF(2)" entry. (The not-binary Meataxe one is the one that most closely resembles what's in the question, by eye.)

I'd thought this might be indicating

> the old TV show called (Rowan and Martin's) [Laugh-In](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rowan_%26_Martin%27s_Laugh-In); "Laugh-In" sounds very slightly like "McLaughlin", and indeed if we take the full form of the name minus its abbreviation we get (Mc)Laugh(l)in

but as OP points out in comments (duh)

> there is in fact a TV show called precisely "The McLaughlin Group" :-).

But why "gold and loud"? Well, the colour

> used in the image (which I'm not sure I would personally call "gold", which may be why I didn't realise that the question was "why is the image the colour it is?" rather than "what about this indicates gold", but never mind) is #898128. The McLaughlin group has 898128000 elements, so I guess that's why it's "gold".

And

> apparently discussions on that show tended to get very *loud*.

I regret the fact that

> my name isn't quite McLaughlin, but it's kinda close and I'm pretty sure I've had someone get it wrong that way at least once :-).

Comment: rot13(Vs lbh frnepu "gur [tebhc anzr]" ba Jvxvcrqvn lbh jvyy frr vg vf gur rknpg anzr bs nabgure gryrivfvba cebtenzzr, urapr gur jbeqcynl gnt. Guvf vf yvxr "gur Qviretrag Frevrf".)

Comment: rot13(Nyfb ybbx ng gur ETO pbqr bs gur pbybhe rzcyblrq.)

Comment: _The McLaughlin Group_ was known for its shouting (see Wikipedia again), hence the loud part.

Comment: Oh. Fair enough, I guess. :-)